# Import personalized newsletter to Mailchimp

Tags: html, css, mailchimp, newsletter

So I've coded a Mailchimp newsletter with their code format.

But the problem is that when I import that newsletter, it don't gets on "drag and drop" mode but goes on "code your own" mode so we only can modify it with code.

I won't touch to that newsletter after, so I would like to modify it with drag and drop for the next ones who'll use it.

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Mailchimp knowledge base](http://kb.mailchimp.com/templates/code/export-template-html):

> Exported drag-and-drop templates will not include the drag-and-drop
>   functionality in their code. When imported into a MailChimp account,
>   drag-and-drop templates can be used to create and send campaigns, but
>   will not be editable in MailChimp. If you want to retain the
>   drag-and-drop functionality for a template, look into using our
>   template sharing feature.

So you have to **save the template and share it**/ save for future sharing.

Here's the link to [How to share a template](http://kb.mailchimp.com/templates/layouts-and-themes/how-to-share-a-template)

Article content:

> 1. Navigate to the Templates page.
> 2. Locate the template you'd like to share by browsing the template
>      list or using the search and filter options.
> 3. Click the drop-down menu for the template and choose Share.
>
> The Share screen provides two ways to share your template's unique
>   URL:
>
> 1. The Share by email option allows you send an email containing the
>      template's link to any valid email address. Enter each email address
>      you want to send the share link to, then click the Share Template
>      button.
> 2. The Share by URL option displays the unique URL for this template.
>      Give this URL to anyone you want to share the template with.

The template can then be edited or used in a Mailchimp campaign by the receiver

Comment: See end paragraphs of Mailchimp knowledge base link for the quote included at the top of answer